# Login to remote TFS server from Windows 7 ultimate

Tags: windows-7, tfs, dns

I want to login to a remote TFS server from my Windows 7 PC.
I have team explorer 2010 and all the necessary tools installed to connect.
I can connect when I use the credentials from FIREFOX or IE (or any browser).

When I connect from VS 2010, I get the following error:

http://manishkungwani.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Error.jpg

My guess is that the domain name needs to be changed from my PC's name: "MANISH-PC"

Please suggest a way to login to the TFS server from my PC!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to try adding the correct credentials to "Manage Windows Credentials" in windows 7: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/05/21/Automatically-connect-to-TFS-under-another-user-account.aspx

Comment: Added the credentials as a Generic credential, now when i try to add a server from VS 2010, it asks for credentials and the same problem persists!

Comment: Well the TFS providers, later gave us the Domain name, which worked, yet the only answer.